# como filtrar con etiquetas <a> en angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Me gustaria poder filtrar por sexo al dar clic en una ancla pero no se como obtener el valor. he intentado asi:

```
<a href="#" ng-value="mujer" ng-model="busqueda.nombre">Mujeres</a>     
<tr ng-repeat="persona in personas | filter:busqueda | orderBy:columna:reverse ">
```

pero no funciona

Comment: aun sigues con el problema? en que puedo ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Segun el ejemplo del que pongo link tendría que ser un string que se busca en el objeto. "busqueda.nombre" en ng-model y en el filter.

```
<a href="#" ng-value="mujer" ng-model="busqueda.nombre">Mujeres</a>     
<tr ng-repeat="persona in personas | filter:busqueda.nombre | orderBy:columna:reverse ">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="universidadApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Filtros - ng-repeat</title>


        <!-- Incluir Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

        <!-- Incluir AngularJS -->
        <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <style>
            .avatar{
                width: 75px;
                height: 75px;
            }

            .puntero{
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="listadoCtrl">

            <h1>Filtros</h1>
            <h4>Para el ng-repeat</h4>
            <hr>

            <div class="row">
                Busqueda:
                <br>
                <input type="text" ng-model="busqueda.nombre"
class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese lo que desea buscar.">
                </br>
                <a href="#" ng-value="mujer"
ng-model="busqueda.nombre" ng-click="ordenarPor('mujer')">Mujeres</a>
<a href="#" ng-value="mujer" ng-model="busqueda.nombre"
ng-click="ordenarPor('hombre')">Hombres</a> <a href="#"
ng-value="mujer" ng-model="busqueda.nombre"
ng-click="ordenarPor('')">Todos</a>
                <br>

                Sexo:
                <br>
                <select ng-model="busqueda.sexo" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Cualquiera</option>
                    <option value="mujer">Mujeres</option>
                    <option value="hombre">Hombres</option>
                </select>
                <br>


            </div>




            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Avatar</th>
                    <th> <a class="puntero"
ng-click="columna='nombre'; reverse = !reverse;"> Nombre</a> </th>
                    <th> <a class="puntero" ng-click="columna='sexo';
reverse = !reverse;"> Sexo</a></th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                    <th>Celular</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="persona in personas | filter:busqueda |
filter:ordenSeleccionado ">
                    <td> <img ng-src="img/{{ persona.avatar }}"
class="avatar img-circle"> </td>
                    <td> {{ persona.nombre }} </td>
                    <td> {{ persona.sexo }}</td>
                    <td> {{ persona.telefono }}</td>
                    <td> {{ persona.celular }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>





        </div><!-- fin del listadoCtrl -->

    </body>
</html>

(function(){

var app = angular.module('universidadApp',[ ]);



app.controller('listadoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

 $scope.filter = function(sexo){
    $scope.sex = sexo;
    console.log(sex)
 }
 $scope.ordenarPor = function(orden) {
    $scope.ordenSeleccionado = orden;

  };

$scope.personas=[
      {
        "id": 0,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Kari Carr",
        "avatar": "kari.jpg",
        "telefono": "(826) 453-3497",
        "celular": "(801) 9175-8136"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Tameka Gamble",
        "avatar": "tameka.jpg",
        "telefono": "(824) 438-2499",
        "celular": "(801) 8595-8337"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Charity Austin",
        "avatar": "charity.jpg",
        "telefono": "(817) 512-2258",
        "celular": "(801) 9375-3830"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Slater Hunt",
        "avatar": "slater.jpg",
        "telefono": "(842) 413-3023",
        "celular": "(801) 9555-1729"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Chen Hanson",
        "avatar": "chen.jpg",
        "telefono": "(966) 520-2696",
        "celular": "(801) 9324-4423"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Obrien Davis",
        "avatar": "obrien.jpg",
        "telefono": "(996) 595-3896",
        "celular": "(801) 8195-2732"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Le Haley",
        "avatar": "le.jpg",
        "telefono": "(967) 527-3286",
        "celular": "(801) 8074-5225"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Lester Carney",
        "avatar": "lester.jpg",
        "telefono": "(994) 465-3542",
        "celular": "(801) 9044-7522"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Rosario Perry",
        "avatar": "rosario.jpg",
        "telefono": "(848) 499-2977",
        "celular": "(801) 8495-0625"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Marilyn Huber",
        "avatar": "marilyn.jpg",
        "telefono": "(982) 580-3235",
        "celular": "(801) 8184-2624"
      }
    ];



}]);





})();
```